# How can I generate varying six number sequences in Excel, using the numbers 1-42, with minimum repeated pairs?

Tags: excel

Using the numbers 1 - 42, I would like to generate a varying number of six number sequences, with the minimum instances of repeated paired numbers (probably in excel)

As a simple example (using 1 - 6) and generating 3 number sequences the results would be something along the lines of

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
1, 2, 4 (repeat of 1, 2 pairing)
1, 3, 5 (repeat of 1, 3 pairing)
2, 3, 4 (repeating 2, 3)
2, 3, 5 (2nd repeat of 2,3 & 3,5)
```

After that my brain starts to stew...

I tried to figure it out manually